# Inserting a node in a pre sorted linked list

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I have been going through the Linkedlist problems on hacker rank and I am currently solving the question which will ask you to insert a node in a sorted doubly linkedlist.

This is my logic I wrote in Java

```
Node SortedInsert(Node head,int data) {

    Node newNode = new Node();
    Node temp = head;
    newNode.data = data;
    newNode.next = null;
    newNode.prev = null;

    if(head == null){
        head = newNode;
    }else{
        while(data > temp.data && temp.next != null){
            temp = temp.next;
        }
        if(temp == head){
            newNode.next = temp;
            temp.prev = newNode;
            head = newNode;
        }else if(data > temp.data){
            newNode.prev = temp;
            temp.next = newNode;
        }else{
            newNode.prev = temp.prev;
            newNode.next = temp;
            temp.prev.next = newNode;
            temp.prev = newNode;
        }

    }

  return head;
}
```

This is the error I get.

```
Your Output (stdout)
Wrong Answer!
Some possible errors:
1. You returned a NULL value from the function. 
2. There is a problem with your logic
Wrong Answer!
Some possible errors:
1. You returned a NULL value from the function. 
2. There is a problem with your logic
```

I have no idea what I did wrong. I really want to know where I went wrong. I know it is easy to find answer online but i think i will learn the best if someone can correct my mistake.

Comment: I hope this example will help you : [Java Program to Implement Sorted Doubly Linked List](http://www.sanfoundry.com/java-program-implement-sorted-doubly-linked-list/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The problem is that you're always inserting the second element in the list before the first element.** Consider the following illustration:

Let the linked list is empty initially. Now you follow your algorithm to insert `1`. The `head == null` case is triggered and `head` points to `newNode` now.

```
x<-1->x
   |
  HEAD
```

Now, you try to insert `2` in the list. You'll see that the `while` loop ends and `temp` now points to `head`, triggering the if condition that follows (`if(temp == head)`).

```
x<-1->x
   |
  HEAD, temp
```

This inserts `2` (incorrectly!) **before** `temp`.

```
x<-2<=>1->x
   |
  HEAD
```

Swapping the order of the conditions should fix the problem:

```
    if(data > temp.data) {    // First, check if you need to insert at the end.
        newNode.prev = temp;
        temp.next = newNode;
    } else if(temp == head) { // Then, check if you need to insert before head.
        newNode.next = temp;
        temp.prev = newNode;
        head = newNode;
    } else {                  // Otherwise, insert somewhere in the middle.
        newNode.prev = temp.prev;
        newNode.next = temp;
        temp.prev.next = newNode;
        temp.prev = newNode;
    }
```

Comment: I wish i could upvote your answer again. This makes sense. Yes you are right the order of conditions is where the issue was.